# Export Enterprise Search from SP2010Server to SP2010Server

Tags: search-scope, export, enterprise-search

Is there a way to export Enterprise Search settings(Scope, managed properties, etc...) from one SP2010 server to another? For example from a Development server to a Production Server.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using PowerShell, both for exporting and importing Your settings. You would need to find the relevant bits and Peaces to Ensure you get everything from search schema, content Sources, crawl rules, etc included.

If you are starting from scratch, consider configuring search using PowerShell and environment specific settings for host names, urls, accounts, etc.

Comment: This sounds like good approach. I wonder if there is a finished script I could use instead of coding something from scratch.